# Limit result from mysql query per column rows Count

Tags: php, mysql, limit-per-group

First, I have a table schema look like this:

```html
CREATE TABLE `list` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `parentId` INT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `parentId`) VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `parentId`) VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `parentId`) VALUES ('3', '1');

INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `parentId`) VALUES ('4', '2');
INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `parentId`) VALUES ('5', '2');
INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `parentId`) VALUES ('6', '2');

INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `parentId`) VALUES ('7', '3');
INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `parentId`) VALUES ('8', '3');
INSERT INTO `list` (`id`, `parentId`) VALUES ('9', '3');
```

I have a query which return this data for example:

```html
| id | parentId |
|----|----------|
|  1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |
|  3 |        1 |
|  4 |        2 |
|  5 |        2 |
|  6 |        2 |
|  7 |        3 |
|  8 |        3 |
|  9 |        3 |
```

All the data above generated from select query:

```
SELECT `id`, `parentId` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id`;
```

I need the result to be max 2 records per parentId. The result is need be look like this:

```html
    | id | parentId |
    |----|----------|
    |  1 |        1 |
    |  2 |        1 |
    |  4 |        2 |
    |  5 |        2 |
    |  7 |        3 |
    |  8 |        3 |
```

How do I achieve this? I've been searching around on the net but seems like getting no luck. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT t.id, t.parentid
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parentid ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM list
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6axVWM6V27Y8GX6MzjET5S/1).
Results:

```
| id  | parentid |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | 1        |
| 2   | 1        |
| 4   | 2        |
| 5   | 2        |
| 7   | 3        |
| 8   | 3        |
```

For previous versions where you can't use window functions, try this (not so efficient for large tables) solution:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM list t
WHERE 2 > (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM list 
  WHERE parentid = t.parentid AND id < t.id
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ex5m1cDkdE5PGJyyrRmoNK/0).

Comment: I try to execute this command **SELECT VERSION()** and the result is **5.5.64-MariaDB**. Tried your query, and mysql giving this error: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY**

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: It works! thanks a lot. I probably will be using the solution for previous version for now. But I'm curious though, why it's not so efficient by the way?

Comment: The correlated subquery in the WHERE clause has to be executed for each one of the rows. This would be a heavy task for a large table.